Error Caused By Taylor Series Approximation In A Mechanics Problem
I'm currently going through "An Introduction to Mechanics" by Kleppner and Kolenkow. On pages 36 - 37, Kleppner discusses how to find an approximate solution to a Physics problem. I have a few questions about this approximation.
Kleppner starts with the expression $\Delta T=T_{0}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}-1}$.
Since we are given that x is very small (in other words, $-1 < x < 1$), we can use the Taylor series of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}}$ to write it as $\Delta T = T_{0}({\frac{-1}{2}x + \frac{3}{8}x^2 - \frac{5}{16}x^3...})$.
This gives us that $\Delta T \approx T_{0}({\frac{-1}{2}x})$.
Kleppner ends by claiming the error of this approximation is less than first neglected term,
$\frac{3}{8}x^2$.
This last part is what is confusing me. Specifically, there are 2 things I'm wondering:

How is Kleppner measuring error? Is it simply the difference between $T_{0}({\frac{-1}{2}x})$ and $\Delta T=T_{0}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}-1}$?

Why is the error of this approximation less than first neglected term, $\frac{3}{8}x^2$? How can this be proven?


Thanks in advance!

For small $x$, the remainder decays to zero. Remember, $x^p \to 0$ when $|x| < 1$.

@SeanRoberson That makes sense to me intuitively, but I'm still not entirely convinced that the error of the approximation is less than $\frac{3}{8}x^2$, just from that reasoning.

@EthanChan -- you write "Kleppner starts with the expression..." Alas, the formula you show is not the same as in reference, p. 36 with tag (1).

The Taylor series alternates in sign, so the alternating series theorem applies.  This gives the error as the same sign as and smaller than the first neglected term.

I think the formula in the book is likely
$$
\Delta T = T_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}}-1\right) \neq T_{0}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}-1}.
$$
That is, in the correct formula, you subtract $1$ after you take the square root, not before.
Indeed the Taylor series for $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x}} - 1$ is
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
where
$$
a_n = (-1)^n \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n - 1)}
                  {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n)}.
$$
If you approximate a function by the first $k$ terms of its Taylor series,
the "error" is the difference between the approximation and the exact value.
That's almost certainly what Kleppner and Kolenkow mean by "error."
If you use only the first term of the series, the error is the difference between $-\frac12 T_0$ and $\Delta T.$
The Taylor series in this exercise is an alternating series and if $x \leq 1$ the terms are decreasing in magnitude. Therefore no matter how many or few terms you use from the start of the series,
the absolute value of the error of the partial sum will always be less than the absolute value of the first omitted term.
This is a relatively elementary result about decreasing alternating series that would be in just about any calculus textbook.
Rather than prove the general theorem (which you can look up),
let's just consider the error in this particular exercise.
The error is
\begin{multline}
\Delta T - \left(-\frac12 T_0 x\right)
 = \frac38 T_0 x^2 
 - \frac5{16} T_0 x^3 + \frac{35}{128} T_0 x^4
 -  \frac{63}{256} T_0 x^5 +- \cdots.
\end{multline}
The right-hand sum can be grouped in either of the following two ways:
$$
\left(\frac38 T_0 x^2 - \frac5{16} T_0 x^3\right)
 + \left(\frac{35}{128} T_0 x^4
 -  \frac{63}{256} T_0 x^5\right) + \cdots,
$$
$$
\frac38 T_0 x^2 - \left(\frac5{16} T_0 x^3
 - \frac{35}{128} T_0 x^4\right)
 - \left(\frac{63}{256} T_0 x^5 - \frac{231}{1024} T_0 x^6\right)
 -  \cdots,
$$
Since the series is decreasing, each set of parentheses contains a positive value, so the (signed) value of the total error is positive (from the first rewriting of the sum) but less than $\frac38 T_0 x^2$ (from the second rewriting of the sum).
If I recall correctly, the usual proof of the alternating decreasing series theorem is similar to these two sums, but written and argued in a more rigorous and general way.

Okay, I understand that by the alternating series test, all the omitted terms must converge to a certain value, since they are decreasing. But how do we know that they value they converge to is less than the first omitted term?

If I've managed to correct all the typos in my formulas, this answer now gives a concrete demonstration of the error bounds for this particular problem.

Taylor's theorem states (roughly speaking) that for a $k$-times differentiable function in the neighbourhood of $x = a$, you can write it as a degree $k$ Taylor polynomial in $(x - a)$ plus a remainder term that is on the order of $(x - a)^k$. In other words,
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2}(x - a)^2 + \ldots + \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x - a)^k + h_k(a) (x - a)^k$$
where $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} h_k(x) = 0$.
If the function can be differentiated at least one more time, you can use the mean value theorem to write the last term as $R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi)}{(k+1)!}(x - a)^{k+1}$ where $\xi$ is some value between $a$ and $x$, which you can use to put bounds on the error in the remainder term especially if $f$ is monotonic.
